# Moving mouse cursor when station is locked (java)

Tags: java, mouse

I have the need at my workstation to disable a long idle.
I've been using a piece of code that moves the mouse on the screen once a while, which worked pretty well.

Lately, our security department applied a smart-card&biometric login policy,
which requires my card to be present inside the keyboard (special slot).
Since then the troubles began.
The process works fine as long as I'm logged in, meaning my card is present, but not working if my card is removed.
(I've been logging the process activity, and everything works fine, but the mouse cursor doesn't move.)

Can someone suggest me a way (or link) so I can solve this matter?

**Edit**

OS: Windows XP

Here's the code that is resposible for moving the mouse.
Notice that I have logged its operation, and tested it: The results outcome logged entries (as if the code was ran) but the mouse cursor wasn't moved on the locked session.

Thanks again

```
package AntiIdle;


import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;


class SimulateMouseAction implements Runnable   {

    /**
     *  Robot object used to move the mouse.
     */
    private Robot iRobot;

    /**
     *  Bed object, so thread could notify sleeping objects.
     */ 
    private Bed bed;


    /**
     *  Default constructor is neutralized.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private SimulateMouseAction ()      {   }


    /**
     *  Constructs class with bed object.
     *  
     *  @param      bed     Bed object to notify the sleepers.
     *  @throws     AWTException if Robot creation fails.
     */
    public SimulateMouseAction  (Bed bed) throws AWTException   {
        this.bed = bed;
        iRobot = new Robot();
    }

    /**
     *  Activates tread.
     */
    public void run()   {
        System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yy hh:mm").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) +  
                "Mouse start");
        Dimension scrSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int x, y;

        for (int prcnt=0; prcnt<100; prcnt++)   {               
            x = (int) scrSize.getWidth() * prcnt / 100;         
            y = (int) scrSize.getHeight() * prcnt / 100;        
            moveMouse(x, y);
        }

        y = (int) scrSize.getHeight() - 20;                         
        for (int prcnt=100; prcnt>0; prcnt--)   {               
            x = (int) scrSize.getWidth() * prcnt / 100;         
            moveMouse(x, y);
        }

        for (int prcnt=0; prcnt<100; prcnt++)   {
            x = (int) scrSize.getWidth() * prcnt / 100;         
            y = (int) scrSize.getHeight() * (100-prcnt) / 100;  
            moveMouse(x, y);

        }
        iRobot.mouseMove((int) scrSize.getWidth()/2, (int) scrSize.getHeight()/2);
        System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yy hh:mm").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) + 
                "Mouse end");
        bed.awakeTheSleepers();
    }   


    /**
     *  Moves mouse cursor to given coordinates.
     *
     *  @param  x   X coordinate.
     *  @param  y   Y coordinate.
     */
    private void moveMouse(int x, int y)    {
        iRobot.mouseMove(x, y);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch(InterruptedException ie)    {
                ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

@Mark Peters: Thanks for repling.  As funny as it seems, they gave me this solution...  I've built a java application which launches some vb script that loads Excel and performs some tasks and create reports. The problem is that it stops launching Excel after a day of idle on my station. Everything else seem to be working (The java application keeps working-I've been logging its activity as well as the mouse mover activity in the attached code above). So as you can see, the security problem you suggested isn't solved either way.  As a rule at my country, I'm forced to have 1 week of vacation in a row at least once a year. Ironically, this what's preventing me from fulfilling this duty.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Unless you provide some code, and a lot more detail (operating system, etc) this is very likely to be closed.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Some pointers - this is **not** a typical thread-based discussion board. If you need to update, in future, edit your question. You've got a link to do that at the bottom of your question. Also, take some time to look around the formatting rules - code is indented four spaces (there's no need for <pre> tags). Don't worry about the post below, I've edited your question and the diamond mods will get to sorting that post out.

Comment: Of course:

OS: win-xp sp3

CPU: core 2 duo E8400 @ 3ghz

Ram: 2 GB

Comment: Moderator note: OP Provided code as an _answer_, I've merged the non-code parts of it t a comment. @OBY, Please _edit_ your question (the 'edit' link) to provide clarification. Stack Overflow is not a forum, answers are reserved for answers to the question, not replies. If you click "Answer your question" it is because you are providing an _answer_ to your own question that you plan to accept. On SO, buttons tend to do _exactly_ what they say.

Comment: How does your security department feel about you circumventing policy?  I would imagine keeping a workstation unlocked without an authorized and authenticated person attending to it is one of the things they're specifically trying to prevent.  So if 1) they are OK with it, then why don't you just ask them for a policy override for you, or 2) if they are not OK with it, then don't you think you're opening quite the corporate can of worms?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't suppress unused warnings.  In this case, it's telling you something useful: overriding the default constructor here to make it private is completely pointless since the default constructor doesn't exist when you've specified an overload.  There is no default constructor that needs to be "neutralized."

Comment: This almost sounds like this: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/ITAPPMONROBOT.aspx